# How to show a layout on demand in android which overlays previously existed views?

Tags: android, layout

For example suppose I have a button like this:
[image]

On clicking the Button I want a layout to be shown under it dynamically which overlays other views.  [image]

How can I achieve something like this ?

Answer (score 0):

> On clicking the Button I want a layout to be shown under it
>   dynamically which overlays other views.

you can do same using [PopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html) see below example:

[How to create popups in Android](http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/05/06/how-to-create-popups-in-android/)

Comment: Thanks it seems it will meet my purpose. I will let you know if I can achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your parent layout you may have to tweak the code slightly but this overall idea should work for you.

Put your login layout below your loginBtn and set the layout to `visibility:gone`

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/loginBtn"
.../>

<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/loginLyt"
android:visibility="gone"
android:layout_below="@id/loginBtn"
...>
<!--your EditTexts and enter btn -->
</RelativeLayout>

<!-- rest of your layout... -->
```

then in your activity use the loginBtn click Listener to toggle the visibility of the loginLyt

```
loginBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
  public void onClick(View v){
    if(loginLyt.getVisibility() == View.GONE){
      loginLyt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }else{
      loginLyt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
  }
});
```